# Magento 2 Run/Execute jquery after KnockoutJS has rendered all elements

Tags: magento2

I want to add some JS code after KO render all element in page. i have try below code in magento 2.2.2

```
require(['uiRegistry','domReady!'], function (r) {
        r.get('.test123', function (el) {
            el.append('<a href="javascript:void(0)">Add New</a>');
        });
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 2):

In Knockout js, there is one function called "**[afterRender](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-4-using-afterrender-afteradd-and-beforeremove)**" Use that to achieve expected output.

Magento 2.x Doc Link for [afterRender](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html#afterrender) binding notifies its subscriber when an associated element is inserted into the DOM.

Sometimes we want to run custom post-processing logic (after DOM ready) on the DOM elements generated by our templates.

For example,

> if we're using a JavaScript widgets library such as jQuery UI and want
>   to intercept templates output so that we can run jQuery UI commands on
>   it to transform some of the rendered elements into date pickers,
>   sliders, or anything else.
>
> Generally, the best way to perform such LOGIC's on DOM elements is to
>   write a [**custom binding**](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html),
>
> but if we really just want to access the **raw
>   DOM elements emitted by a template**, we can use **`afterRender`**.

Pass a function reference (either a function literal, or give the name of a function on your view model), and Knockout will invoke it immediately after rendering or re-rendering our template.

For example,

```
<div data-bind='template: { name: "personTemplate",
                            data: myData,
                            afterRender: applyOurLogicAfterDOMReady }'> </div>
```

and define a corresponding function on your view model (i.e., the object that contains myData):

```
viewModel.applyOurLogicAfterDOMReady = function(elements) {
    // "elements" is an array of DOM nodes just rendered by the template
    // You can add custom post-processing logic here
}
```

If we're using `foreach`, Knockout will invoke `afterRender` callback for **each item added to our observable array**.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setInterval` like this:-

```
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui','uiRegistry','domReady!'], function(r){

    setInterval(function () {
        r.get('.test123', function (el) {
            el.append('<a href="javascript:void(0)">Add New</a>');    
        });
    },3000);       
});
```

Code may require fixes, but the point is to use `setInterval`

Comment: setInterval is not good way for this

Comment: `setInterval` not guarantee to do a trick all time

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 'ko' to dependencies

```
require(['uiRegistry','domReady!', 'ko'], function (r) {
    r.get('.test123', function (el) {
        el.append('<a href="javascript:void(0)">Add New</a>');
    });
```